# how to arrange data in a date column according to the quarters

Tags: sql

how to arrange data in a date column according to the quarters

```
select employeeid , datepart(quarter,submitteddate)  as quarter ,
datepart(year,submitteddate) 
from t_performanceheader
group by datepart(year,submitteddate),datepart(quarter,submitteddate), employeeid
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.

Comment: What do you get when you run your query? When you say arrange, do you mean sort? I would probably add ```order by``` in addition to your group by.